# Magento 2 Newsletter Error Invalid Method Interceptor::loadByCustomer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, magento2.4

Magento 2 Error Invalid Method Interceptor::loadByCustomer

[image]

{"0":"M\u00e9todo inv\u00e1lido Vendor\Module\Model\Subscriber\Interceptor::loadByCustomer","1":"#1 Vendor\Module\Observer\Login->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:88]\n#2 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:74]\n#3 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch()

**Code:**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Login implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;
    /**
     * @var Subscriber
     */
    private $subscriber;
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        Subscriber $subscriber,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->subscriber = $subscriber;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if($this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
                $checkSubscriber = $this->subscriber->loadByCustomer($this->session->getCustomerId(), $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                if($checkSubscriber->getSubscriberStatus() === 1) {
                    ...
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution, change your code:

**Change** loadByCustomer to loadByCustomerId

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Login implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @var Subscriber
     */
    private $subscriber;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Session $session
     * @param Subscriber $subscriber
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        Subscriber $subscriber,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->subscriber = $subscriber;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if($this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
                $customerId = $this->session->getCustomerId();
                if ($customerId === null) {
                    $this->logger->warning(__('Something went wrong customerId.'));
                } else {
                    try {
                        $subscriber = $this->subscriber->loadByCustomerId((int)$customerId);
                        if($subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() === 1) {
                        ...
                        }
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}
```